# How to execute a php loop in an andWhere clause using QueryBuilder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I would like to execute this type of query using QueryBuilder in my FakeRepository.php (it's for a search form where the user can check some boxes).

```
  if (sizeof($p['types']) > 0) {
         $qb->andWhere(  
               foreach ($p['types'] as $type_id) 
                    {'type.id=' .$type_id.' OR ' }
               '1=0');
         }
```

But I have an error with my syntax but I don't know how to fix it :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH, expecting ')' in /MyBundle/Entity/FakeRepository.php
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first construct your OR condition and then pass it to the query builder

```
   $first = true;
   $orQuery = '';
   foreach ($p['types'] as $type_id) 
       if ($first) {
           $first = false;
       } else {
           $orQuery .= ' OR ';
       }

       $orQuery .= 'type.id=' .$type_id;
   }
   $qb->andWhere($orQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to keep QueryBuilder functionality

```
$orX = $qb->expr()->orX();

foreach ($types as $key => $type) {
        $orX->add($qb->expr()->eq('types', ':types'.$key));
        $qb->setParameter('types'.$key, $type->getId());
    }

$qb->andWhere($orX);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also resove this problem:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($p['types'] as $type_id){
    $arr[] = $qb->expr()->orX("type.id = $type_id");
}
$qb->andWhere(join(' OR ', $arr));
```